# Im trying to figure out how to deal a card from the deck in my card game class

Tags: java, bluej

Im finding this hard since im not allowed to use arrays for the Deck class instead i have to create an object for it like `private Deck deck;`(you 'll see what i mean in the code)

This method takes a
card from the deck and adds it to the player's hand.

Heres the Card, Deck, Game Class

```
public class Card
{
    public static final String HEARTS = "hearts";
    public static final String DIAMONDS = "diamonds";
    public static final String CLUBS = "clubs";
    public static final String SPADES = "spades";

    private String description;   
    private String suit;      
    private int value;

    public Card()
    {
        description = "Joker";
        suit        = "Spades";
        value       = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Card
     * @param description e.g. "Ten"
     * @param suit e.g. "Hearts"
     * @param value e.g. 10
     */
    public Card(String description, String suit, int value)
    {
        setDescription(description);
        setSuit(suit);
        setValue(value);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the suit.
     * @return suit as a String
     */
    public String getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value.
     * @return value as an int
     */
    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the description.
     * @return description as a String
     */
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the suit
     * @param suit e.g."Hearts"
     */
    public final void setSuit(String suit)
    {
        if((suit != null)&& 
            (suit.equalsIgnoreCase(HEARTS)) ||
            (suit.equalsIgnoreCase(DIAMONDS)) ||
            (suit.equalsIgnoreCase(CLUBS))||
            (suit.equalsIgnoreCase(SPADES))){
            this.suit = suit;
        }
        else {
            this.suit = "unknown suit";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the description
     * @param description e.g. "Ten"
     */
    public final void setDescription(String description)
    {
       if(description != null) {
          this.description = description; 
       }
       else {
          this.description = "unknown description";
       }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value
     * @param value of this card e.g. 10
     */
    public final void setValue(int value)
    {
        if(value > 0 && value <= 10) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        else {
            this.value = 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return string containing description and suit
     */
    public String getInfo()
    {
        return description + " of " + suit;
    }
}
```

Deck Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Deck of cards.
 * 
 * 
 *
 */
public class Deck
{
    private ArrayList<Card> deck;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Deck
     * Creates a new container for Card objects
     */
    public Deck()
    {
        deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    }

    /**
     * Add a card to the deck.
     * @param Card to be added
     */
    public void addCard(Card cardToAdd)
    {
        deck.add(cardToAdd);
    }

    /**
     * Take the first card from the deck.
     * @return Card or null
     */
    public Card takeCard()
    {
        if(deck.isEmpty()) {
            return null; 
        }
        else {    
            Card top = deck.get(0);
            deck.remove(0);
            return top;
            //return  deck.remove(0); // get the top card
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the contents of the deck.
     */
    public void showDeck()
    {
        for(Card eachCard : deck) {
            System.out.println(eachCard.getDescription()+ 
                            " of " + eachCard.getSuit());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the size of the deck
     * @return deck size
     */
    public int getDeckSize()
    {
        return deck.size();
    }

}
```

Heres where im a little stuck. also with my

```
public void showHand() 

    is getting a java.lang.NullPointerException
at Game.showHand(Game.java:31)
```

Game Class:

```
         import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Write a description of class Game here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Game
{
    private InputReader reader;
    private Deck deck;
    private ArrayList<Card> hand;
    private static final int MAX = 5;

    public Game()
    {
        reader = new InputReader();
        deck = new Deck();
        hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
    }

    public void dealCard()
    {
       //<---- not sure what to do with this one
        }
    }

    public void showHand()//<----- not sure if this one is even right
    {                       //compiles fine but when i call the method it gets
        //
        for(Card eachCard: hand){
            System.out.println(eachCard.getDescription()+
                " of " + eachCard.getSuit());
            }
}
}
```

Any help appreciated!! p.s i know how to add a card from the Card class but not sure how to do it from the Deck class

Comment: seems that hand is empty, where is the code that initialize the hand?

Comment: Just pointing out that you are forgetting about your `Card#getInfo()`-method in `Game#showHand()`. I'm referring to the `println`-statement

Comment: btw im not sure what you mean by initialize the hand? dont i do that with the arraylist?

Comment: yeah but in the code posted, there's no point where you add a card to the hand, so i thinked that something wrong will be there

Comment: yea i know that code doesnt work. sorry forgot to delete it. im not sure how to figure it out tho still.

Comment: still dont understand what to do, since i cant use indexes its hard to remove the top card from the deck any other way to do this??

Comment: Is this `Deck` class supposed to be generic for any kind of card game or is it intended to only represent a standard deck of 52 cards? If the later, you should initialize the list of cards in the constructor and perhaps also provide a `shuffle()` method reset the deck and mix up the cards.

Comment: its supposed to just be generic i believe

Answer (score 1):

You're code seems to work fine, I think you should look at how you initilize the deck.

I tried it, adding this :

```
    deck = new Deck();
    Card myCard = new Card();
    myCard.setDescription("Ace");
    myCard.setSuit("spades");
    myCard.setValue(11);
    Card mySecondCard = new Card();
    mySecondCard.setDescription("king");
    mySecondCard.setSuit("hearts");
    mySecondCard.setValue(4);
    hand = new ArrayList<Card>();

    deck.addCard(myCard);
    deck.addCard(mySecondCard);

    System.out.println("content of deck :");
    deck.showDeck();

    hand.add(deck.takeCard());
    System.out.println("content of hand after taking top card:");
    showHand();
```

As a kind of initilalizing, in order to see where your exception could be raised (I was quite sceptical), and it perfectly returned:

content of deck :
Ace of spades
king of hearts

content of hand :
Ace of spades

So I suggest you to check your input first of all.

Then you should create ENUM in order to handle each type of card and there values, A shuffling method, a dealing method (you may parametrized it with a number of card to take from the deck), ...

Answer (score 0):

yeah, now that i've thinked about, "hand" was empty because you fill it from "deck" that is in turn empty. Maybe you can define a method "initDeck" in deck class that fills the deck with random cards, and call it from game constructor. or maybe you already do this out of the game class, but in that case you should pass the deck to game!

Comment: what i do to test this is create a card on the object bench, create a deck on the object bench, use the addCard method to add a card to the deck. then i expect the dealcard to deal the top card (the only card in the deck at the time) but even when i do this its null 00000 whatever u wanna call it haha.

Comment: i tried that but im not sure how to just get the top card from the deck, rather then adding the whole deck to the hand

Comment: in game class you create a new instance of "deck" that will be obiviously empty. if you want to use a deck created in some other part of the code, you need to pass that by constructor or add a method "setDeck" to Game

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a controller or something which will randomly mix the cards to the deck, you just init the array of card at the deck but you dont add cards to it.

Comment: i add the cards to the deck externally, im using blueJ

Comment: you have to deal some cards first as above said hand.add(deck.takeCard()); and then see if the hand has cards, also you have to check if(eachCard!=null{System.out.println(eachCard.getDescription()+
                " of " + eachCard.getSuit());}                         if your public Card takeCard() returns null it means that the deck is empty and you have to add your data to the deck first to take card from it.

Comment: ok i am starting to get it. also should i pass in any parameters to this method or when i call dealCard() method will it just automatically deal the cards?

Comment: Which method do you mean? I dont know what you want to do but i think that you have to do something like for(int i=0; i<howmanycardyouwanttohavetothehabd; i++) {hand.add(deck.takeCard());}

Comment: how do i see if the hand has cards each time i call this method and inspect the object of deck there never seems to be a card taken out of it and never adds it to the hand. the only way i ever got it to add to the hand was to add a parameter Card c, like so 'private void(Card c)' {hand.add(c); but this calls the card class not actually a 'Card' from the deck. if u know what i mean.